# socket client multi threading quickfix/n

Tags: c#, quickfix

I want to create multi threaded initiator in quick fix/n,c#.

Is it possible to create multi threaded initiator that send quick fix messages to multiple servers.

I can see multi threaded acceptor in quick fix/n.Please give your suggestions.Thank you.

Comment: So basically you want to send messages to multiple socket? If yes I believe you can add multiple sessions.

Comment: just add different connection setting to your session config file and the should be initiatied

Comment: Hi Sriram , robthewolf, what If I  have two messages to send to the different servers with different socket connect host and connect port.For each object sending, I have to create different sessions and send these objects.Can you give me suggestions.Thanks for your replies.